# Sequelize transactions rollback on raw queries doesn't work

Tags: transactions, sequelize.js, rollback

Sequelize rollback doesn't work on my transaction.

This is an example code:

```javascript
    return sequelize.transaction({
      isolationLevel: "SERIALIZABLE",
      autocommit: false
    },function (t) {

      return sequelize.query('DELETE FROM Task WHERE id=:id',
      {
        replacements:{"id":id},
        type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
      })
      .then(function () {
        // the query was successful but I still want to roll back
        t.rollback();
      });
   });
```

I checked the console:

**Executing (aaf94974-d646-4056-9cfa-0c53f1b1b3e3): START TRANSACTION;**

**Executing (aaf94974-d646-4056-9cfa-0c53f1b1b3e3): SET SESSION TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;**

**Executing (default): DELETE FROM Task WHERE id=6**

**Executing (aaf94974-d646-4056-9cfa-0c53f1b1b3e3): ROLLBACK;**

But the rollback doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This not described in sequalize documentation, but I find [usage example in sequalize tests](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/e6c42a4acc4af0caf20c9562c247784621982146/test/integration/sequelize.transaction.test.js#L70).

```
return this.sequelize.query(query, { transaction: t }).bind(this).then(function() {
    return this.User.create({ name: 'foo' });
 })
```

So, you just need to pass `transaction` option into `query` call:

```
return sequelize.query('DELETE FROM Task WHERE id=:id',
{
    replacements:{"id":id},
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT
})
```

Comment: too old, but.. I am passing the parameter transaction in that object, but it also doesnt rollback